# Editing existing Sonata Admin form uses wrong embedded form ID

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I've got a problem when editing an existing form in Sonata Admin. The embedded form is one-to-one related to the parent form.

The two entities are called 'ticket' and 'ticket_planning', both with several fields. A 'ticket' can be in different states, e.g. "new", "accepted", "plannable", "planned" and "closed". The state is stored in one of the ticket fields. The entities both have a field 'ID', the entity 'ticket_planning' has a field 'ticket_id'

When a 'ticket' is in the 'plannable' state, I embed the 'ticket_planning' form.

The problem shows up when both a ticket and a ticket_planning with the same ID exists, but they do not belong to each other. Instead of giving  an empty embedded ticket_planning form, it returns the ticket_planning form with the same ID as the ticket form.

When there is no ticket_planning with the same ID as the ticket, it all works like I want: an empty embedded field shows up. When a ticket_planning exists with the ticket_id field filled, I can perfectly edit the related ticket: the right ticket_planning is returned.

What am I doing wrong here?

The relevant part of Ticket.orm.xml looks like:

```
<one-to-one field="ticket_planning" target-entity="TicketPlanning" mapped-by="ticket">
    <cascade>
        <cascade-persist/>
    </cascade>
</one-to-one>
```

TicketPlanning.orm.xml:

```
<one-to-one field="ticket" target-entity="Ticket" inversed-by="ticket_planning">
    <join-column name="ticket_id" referenced-column-name="id" />
</one-to-one>
```

The line adding the ticket_planning in TicketAdmin:

```
->add('ticket_planning', 'sonata_type_admin', array('allow_extra_fields' => true))
```

Comment: Are you confused with uni- and bidirectional relationships? Is it necessary to get the ticket by the condition ticketplanning? btw the join-column is not necessary.

Comment: Well, I think I'm not. :) I have to show info about the planning when showing the ticket and I need the ticket when showing TicketRepair. TicketRepair is embedded in TicketPlanning. It all works like a charm, except the 'intelligence' to return the wrong ticketPlanning.

Comment: Debug symfony and find out which entities doctrine returns. If still buggy, check the underlying query. If stll buggy (block 2 :) - bad..), there is something bad with your associations. If one of these tests is positive the bug is in the sonata admin/symfony forms. You can override Sonata-Controller or go in some hooks. In [Symfony2-form-collection-fields](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#by-reference) have a look at by_reference.